# Error al mostras archivo pdf desde php

Tags: php, pdf

Intento ver un archivo pdf en el navegar desde que ya subi previamente, el problema esta que el navegador me dice "Se ha producido un error al cargar el documento PDF." el codigo si encuentra el archivo pero no lo muestra
Este es codigo php:

```
$file=$_GET["fac"];
$file="view/facs/".$file;

echo $file;

if (file_exists($file)) {
header("Content-type: application/pdf");
header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=".$_GET["fac"]);
header("Content-Length:".filesize($file));
readfile("view/facs/".$_GET['fac']);
exit;
}else{
    echo "Archivo no existe";
}
```

y en el navegador obtengo el siguiente codigo:

```
<embed name="EFFDDD294694F3E270C922961C570712" style="position:absolute; left: 0; top: 0;" width="100%" height="100%" src="about:blank" type="application/pdf" internalid="EFFDDD294694F3E270C922961C570712">
```

Comment: creo que te faltan datos... como creas la etiqueta embed, el php manda algun error warning o notice, verifica si tienes activos el reporte de errores, etc???

Comment: Hola, creería que te hace falta la `url` completa del `pdf`, te dejo un ejemplo `src="http://example.com/the.pdf"`